# Do I need a boarding pass to go from Terminal 1 to Terminal 2 at Munich Airport?

Tags: luggage, layovers, check-in, muc

I want to transit at Munich airport without going out of the transit area. I arrive in Munich with Thai Airways Terminal 2 and depart from Terminal 1 Condor to my non-European final destination.

1- Do I need a boarding pass to travel from T2 to T1?

Given that I can't (visa required for my country of origin) leave the transit zone.

2-Can my partner (we are in the same ticket) drop off my checked baggage as well as his at the drop off point without me having to be present?

Comment: Can you split this into two separate questions?

Comment: For (2) - Why would your partner need to drop off your checked baggage in Munich? If you're on a single booking for both flights, your baggage will most likely be transferred to Condor automatically; it's not like in the US where even transiting passengers need to touch their bags at the transit airport.

Answer (score 5):

1. No, you do **not** need a boarding pass to take the bus from T2 to T1.
2. I called Munich airport to confirm this, and while they don't like it, it will be OK if your partner explains the situation to the Condor check-in staff.

However, given that you don't have a visa, you may well not be allowed to board a plane, since you have two separate bookings and the airline will consider Munich your final destination.

Contact Thai Airways and clear this up with them.

Comment: I read OP's post several times and nowhere does it mention two bookings. Thai is fully Star Alliance and Condor is also , sort of, it's 100% Lufthansa owned so it's not impossible this is a single book.

Comment: @chx They would not have to collect and re-check the luggage otherwise; hence, question 2 would be void

Comment: It's conceivable that the OP _thought_ baggage works the same way as when transiting through an American airport, where you need to re-drop your bags even on a single ticket.

Comment: Also in case of a single booking, he would have a boarding pass already.

Comment: @HenningMakholm OP at least knows he can (and must) remain in the transit area, which is impossible in the US except at Anchorage on Cathay Pacific